# PHP Curl and headers problem

Tags: php, http, curl, content-type, httpresponse

I have asked a question on this before, but again ran into problems and just cannot solve it. I have a internal proxy server and a content server. The code on the proxy server is this. (Some comments may be wrong but leaving here to convey what is my understanding):

```
<?php
session_start();
$data_server_url = "http://my_data_server_url/";
$i_var_prefix="i_var_";

$process_headers_separately=0;
//$process_headers_separately=1;
// WARNING! Has problems with GZIPPED DATA!
// AVOID/REMOVE OPTION ALLTOGETHER
// (Set to 1 if you want to catch received headers
// and send explicit headers to clients)
//-----------------------------------------

// Other important request dependent 'SERVER' variables.
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
{ $_POST["${i_var_prefix}_HTTPS"]=$_SERVER['HTTPS']; };

if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
{ $_POST["${i_var_prefix}_REMOTE_ADDR"]=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; };

$request_uri="";
if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) { $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; };
$curl_url="${data_server_url}${request_uri}";

$field_array= array(
      'Accept' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT',
      'Accept-Charset' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET',
      'Accept-Encoding' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING',
      'Accept-Language' => 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE',
      'Connection' => 'HTTP_CONNECTION',
      'Host' => 'HTTP_HOST',
      'Referer' => 'HTTP_REFERER',
      'User-Agent' => 'HTTP_USER_AGENT'
      );

$curl_request_headers=array();

foreach ($field_array as $key => $value) {
   if(isset($_SERVER["$value"])) {
      $server_value=$_SERVER["$value"];
      $curl_request_headers[]="$key: $server_value";
   }
};
//------
session_write_close();

//Open connection
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_COOKIE,session_name()."=".session_id().";");
//Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, $process_headers_separately);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_request_headers);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "identity");


//Execute post
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);

//Close connection
curl_close($curl_handle);

if ($process_headers_separately) {
   list($headers,$content)=explode("\r\n\r\n",$result,2);
   foreach (explode("\r\n",$headers) as $hdr) {
      header($hdr);
   }
   echo $content;
} else {
   echo $result;
}    
?>
```

**Problem 1:** With the current code, even if the Content-Type returned by the data_server is text/plain,  the content-type seen by the client is text/html.
For example, see http://sarcastic-quotes.com/robots.txt  This request goes to the file above. I have checked that the *data server* is actually returning Content-Type as text/plain. But through the proxy, client sees content-type in response headers as text/html.

**Problem 2:** Note the use of variable `process_headers_separately`. If I set it to 1, then the browser tries to download a gzip file instead of displaying the contents (no matter what content-type the data server returns). Thus, there is some logical bug in that code flow.

I just want the above code to work as an internal proxy that seamlessly acts as a bridge between my data server and the client. Any thoughts would be appreciated, I am really confused with how to correctly handle the headers above.

regards,
JP

---

I have found the cause of the problem when process_headers_separately=1 (browser downloading file instead of displaying). But it is SO strange and am unable to solve it. Problem: If I uncomment the lines `if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) { $_POST["${i_var_prefix}_REMOTE_ADDR"]=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; };`
then things start working fine! Strange!

Its gotta be some crazy whitespace problem like Neil suggested.

Anyways, trying to fix this - I have spent 3 days (2 earlier and 1 now) due to this crazy bug :(. Thanks to Neil and RF for helping me on this.

Comment: RabidFire's approach of curl_getinfo works in that atleast the content type is correctly transffered. However, I am trying the 'relay all' approach. In that, no matter what I try, the browser is always trying to download the file. It appears that the whole header and content stuff is compressed again by the proxy server, and some sort of double compression is taking place. If I uncompress the downloaded file, the uncompressed file has the headers as readable text and actual page content as gzipped data.

Comment: If your browser's trying to download the file, then either your `Content-Type` header is set to something the browser can't display, like `application/octet-stream`, or the `Content-Disposition` header is set incorrectly. Compressed data not being decompressed, with the right headers, should at least just show gobbledegook.

Comment: Can you edit the question to reflect any changes you've made to the code? I'll have another squiz at it.

Comment: I have put the new code, with combined changes from your and RF's suggestions. thanks

Comment: Make sure there's no mismatch between the `Content-Encoding` response header from CURL and the output it actually serves. CURL will try to decompress content if it thinks it can, so you'll need to recompress it using `gzcompress()` or `gzdeflate()`. Apart from compressing, is your content type issue still around? Also, try replacing `$curl_request_headers` with a treatment of `apache_request_headers()`. Sometimes, when you use `mod_rewrite`, you end up with stuff like `$_SERVER['HTTP_REDIRECT_ACCEPT_ENCODING']` instead of what you're looking for.

Comment: I thought setting CURLOPT_ENCODING to identity would prevent it from recompressing (but there is no difference with or without using this in any case). I am unable to check Content-Type for the responses now (using the usual method in Chrome Ctrl+Shift+I) - because it is only showing the debug response data for requests that are actually displayed by the browser - is there any alternate way to check?

Comment: If you're on Windows, I use fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) to spy on what's going back and forth through HTTP. Just tell your browser to use it as a proxy, then check the RAW tab. It also has an 'autodecode' thingy that automatically decodes compressed content - but leave it off so you can tell when stuff is compressed. If you don't want to use a proxy, just write lots and lots of stuff to log files. I know, I know, it's tedious, but it takes out a lot of mystery and guess work.

Comment: One other thing you can try - `ini_set('display_errors',0)`. Sounds kooky... but PHP spitting out notices of otherwise innocuous issues can fault your browser's decompression software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all looks pretty kosher. The only discrepancy I can see is that SOME servers only separate headers with `\n`, rather than `\r\n`. But that's probably not the issue.

Can you try writing `var_export(explode("\r\n",$headers),true)` to a file and see what comes out?

Re your gzip issue, make sure there's no trailing whitespace after your closing `?>`, or even safer, change `echo $result` to `die($result)`. Obviously if you don't pass on the CURL response's headers, Apache will make up its own, so you're going to need that `CURLOPT_HEADER` flag.

Is CURL decompressing the response for you? If so, you may need to intervene with the `Content-Encoding` and `Content-Length` response headers.

n.

Comment: Thanks Neil. The splitting is happening correctly with \r\n, that I checked.  This whitespace thing is tricky and dangerous - I never bothered about it! But in the present file, there is not whitespace. I don't thing curl is decompressing the response because I set CURLOPT_ENCODING as "identity".

Comment: Does "die" count as an error or it is perfectly 'neat' practice to use die?

Comment: No, it won't log anything or throw any exceptions. I use it for a lot of AJAX responder stuff, and yes, with gzcompress as well. die() is perfect for a "final output" operation; it basically means "send this stuff and then pull the plug". Supporting gzip can only be a good thing, so I'd recommend taking the time to iron it out. Your headers won't be compressed, only your response body, and you can use gzuncompress() and gzinflate() to process response bodies further if you need to.

Comment: curl_getinfo() is more intended for internal processing than relaying. You're on the right track with parsing the raw response, because you don't need to translate anything; you can just relay it all back to the client. In fact, you can do the same on the way in too; rather than picking through $_SERVER, since you're on apache, as long as you're not using CGI, you can just use apache_request_headers() instead.

Comment: CURLOPT_ENCODING interferes with the Accept-Encoding request header. Since you're passing your request's Accept-Encoding on to the server, you may want to omit this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following lines of code:

```
//Execute post
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$result_info = curl_getinfo($curl_handle);
```

And then:

```
} else {
    if (isset($result_info['content_type'])) {
        header("Content-Type: {$result_info['content_type']}");
    }
    echo $result;
}
```

Basically, your proxy server is the one that's returning the data. So, that's where you would have to set the Content-Type. By default, this would be html. But if you check if the CURL response had a specific Content-Type and manage to set that, it'll do the trick! :)

Let us know if that works for you.

---

I kinda understand what you're trying to do now. So here's how to get the headers in your proxy's response:

If you set the CURLOPT_HEADER option to 1, you will receive the headers in your output which will let you do this:

```
// Grab the headers from the result
if ($process_headers_separately) {
    list($header_string, $content) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
    // OR :
    // $header_string = substr($result, 0, $result_info['header_size']);
    $headers = http_parse_headers($header_string);
    foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
        header("$key: $value");
    }
}
```

I suggest using the http_parse_headers function because of the reasons mentioned by the poster of the first answer. I'm not sure if this will solve your gzipping problem. Let us know.

Comment: aha. curl_getinfo looks neat. pardon my lack of knowledge on this - but can there be multiple headers in a response? I mean just like result_info['content_type'], should I look for other specific fields in result_info?

Comment: Well, nothing relevant to your current problem: response status, last-modified, timing information, etc. `curl_getinfo` returns a number of things: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php - you could get only a single piece like so: `$content_type = curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE)`

Comment: This works! I wonder if above code will ensure that other header fields (like expiry, keep-alive, cache-control etc are automatically set to those returned by the 'data-server'?

Comment: @RabidFire : Incidentally, that solves the earlier problem of robots.txt newline. Interesting that I had to split the question into 2 problems and you happened to help on both :) thanks.

Comment: Also, though things work,  I am bit confused  - if we set curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); then will the server not return headers at all OR will they just be not part of result but still available via curl_getinfo?

Comment: The latter is correct. Bare in mind that you may miss other important headers, like those relating to caching etc.

Comment: Oh. Yes, thats what I was wondering. In that case, do you think its best to use the approach of CURLOPT_HEADER=1 and then splitting header and content in the response? In which case, I am sort of back to step 1 :)

Comment: Sorry, but, yeah. I know it's a bit trickier because of compression and whatnot, but it's a much broader-sweeping solution that takes you from "relay content-type" to "relay all headers", which is what you really need.

Comment: I've edited my answer to try and send all the headers. Let us know if that works for you. If it does, you could permanently remove the `if` condition, and always set CURLOPT_HEADER to 1.

Comment: @RabidFire I'd have to suggest JP19's method is superior to using http_parse_headers, because it'll also relay the status code line, eg `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. Also, `http_parse_headers` isn't available on a lot of servers. Sorry to burst that bubble :)

Comment: @JP19 - Following up on Neil's words, you could use some of the user contributed functions on this page: http://php.net/http_parse_headers :)

Comment: @RF: Yes, if I can get that gzip thing to work, I plan to permanently remove the `if`.

Comment: Nevertheless (and god forbid this turns into a debate hehe) you'd just be pulling the headers apart only to put them straight back together again. @JP19 what's the gzip issue? Is the browser spitting chips? What does firebug have to say about it? Some browsers want `Content-Length` to be included before touching compressed data...